# Opt out of "Technical Communities Recently Active Questions"

Tags: support

There appears to be a UI experiment running, where for those impacted, the front page of SO contains a selection of HNQ summaries from other technical communities.

I really, *really* hate this. It's not at all information-dense, the questions aren't frequently rotated, and they smell like things that have already gotten enough attention that they don't need answers.

My settings page has an option to opt out of the HNQ *sidebar*, but I don't have anything against the sidebar; it's nicely out-of-the-way. How can I get rid of the front-and-center questions from other SE communities that come before those from the community in which I'm trying to participate?